What is the total number of coloring with maximum color $k$ is possible for a $n$ vertex graph using greedy coloring?
Greedy coloring methodology colors a graph following a permutation of vertices, and while coloring a vertex, it puts the minimum color not assigned to its neighbor.
Consider a graph G with $n$ vertices. What is the total number of k-coloring of G  generated by greedy coloring?  We may call this number as greedy chromatic number $P_g(G,k)$. Note that it's less than the chromatic polynomial with $k$ color ($G$ is $k$ colorable).

What thoughts/progress have you made on this problem?

@TonyMathew it is known that number of maximum independent sets are $O(3^{n/3}/(n/3))$. Also greedy coloring splits the graphs into max independent sets.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#:~:text=Maximal%20independent%20set,-Main%20article%3A%20Maximal&text=Every%20graph%20contains%20at%20most,given%20by%20the%20Padovan%20sequence.
